# How to loopcut a Square-based Pyramid?

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to loop-cut a Square based Pyramid, so that there is multiple bands around the sloped sides?

Edit: Sorry, my bad, but when I said triangular prism, I was thinking about a pyramid, Changed that just now. Sorry again! Though the prism answer was a nice knowledge to know.

Comment: try knife tool (K)

Comment: @Bithur Yeah, but is there a way to do multiple (around 210) cuts somewhat quickly?

Comment: loopcut should do that but if not, try knife projrct

Comment: Like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/QXNs4.png ?

Comment: @stacker Sorry, my bad, I changed it now to Squared based pyramid, which is what I was asking for, sry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless it is square-based or not, you can always select all sloped edges, then hit <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide, then tweak the number of cuts as you want.

[image]

Another trick is to first bevel the pole vertex, with a very small value, to make all sloped faces **quads** (they might still look like triangles , but they are actually quads now), then you can use loop cut tool to cut them. After that, just remove the extra vertices with **Remove Doubles** tool.

[image]

Comment: Thank-you!, can't believe that I haven't tried to just select the sloped sides when subdividing!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to cut it **around** slope sides do it with the loopcut tool <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and adjust the number of cuts with middle wheel or input number with keyboard.

[image]

If you need to cut it **along** slope sides:

1. Subdivide your prism with <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide* as many times as you need:

   [image]
2. Delete the middle part:

   [image]
3. Select everything and convert to n-gons with <kbd>F</kbd>, then hit <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ***Loop Subdivide*** tool. Just hover your cursor over the area of the mesh you want to loop-cut (place it near the edge), press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and input the number of cuts you want to use using numerical keyboard buttons. Approve the operation by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.

[image]

You can see the details here:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Loop_Subdivide